# Increments of birth-death process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Reading about birth-death processes i encountered a formula which i can't derive
It's [here](http://cs.nyu.edu/cs/faculty/mishra/COURSES/09.HPGP/scribe3), page 4, number (7)-(8).

$P_{i,i+1}(h)=P(X(t+h)-X(t)=1|X(t)=1)=\frac{(\lambda_ih)^1e^{-\lambda_ih}}{1!}\frac{(\mu_ih)^0e^{-\mu_ih}}{0!}+o(h)$

I understand that here we have 2 (independent?) nonhomogenous Poisson processes for births and for deaths, and that they have distributions respectively

$P(N_b(t+h)-N_b(t)=k|N_b(t)=i)=\frac{(\lambda_ih)^ke^{-\lambda_ih}}{k!}$ $P(N_d(t+h)-N_d(t)=k|N_d(t)=i)=\frac{(\mu_ih)^ke^{-\mu_ih}}{k!}$

So the initial formula, as i suppose, should somehow lead to

$P_{i,i+1}(h)=P(X(t+h)-X(t)=1|X(t)=1)=P(N_b(t+h)-N_b(t)=1|N_b(t)=i)P(N_d(t+h)-N_d(t)=k|N_d(t)=i)+\sum_{}^{}$

Where some $\sum_{}^{} \in o(h)$

But how do i get to this point?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
P_{i,i+1}(h) &= P(X(t+h)-X(t)=1\mid X(t) = i) \\
&= P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} \left[N_b(t+h)-N_b(t)=j \;\cap\; N_d(t+h)-N_d(t)=j-1\right]\;\bigg|\; X(t)=i\right) \\ 
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{i.e. $1$ birth, $0$ deaths, or $2$ births, $1$ death, or $3$ births, $2$ deaths, etc. } \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} P\left(\left[N_b(t+h)-N_b(t)=j \;\cap\; N_d(t+h)-N_d(t)=j-1\right]\;\bigg|\; X(t)=i\right) \\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{since the union is disjoint} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} P\left(N_b(t+h)-N_b(t)=j\mid X(t)=i\right) P\left(N_d(t+h)-N_d(t)=j-1\mid X(t)=i\right) \\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{by independence of $N_b$ and $N_d$} \\
& \\
&= P\left(N_b(t+h)-N_b(t)=1\mid X(t)=i\right) P\left(N_d(t+h)-N_d(t)=0\mid X(t)=i\right) + o(h) \\
& \\
&=\frac{(\lambda_ih)^1e^{-\lambda_ih}}{1!}\frac{(\mu_ih)^0e^{-\mu_ih}}{0!}+o(h).
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, thank you. However i see the problem. N_b and N_d are independent, but, as i understand, they should be not only independent, but conditionally independent under X(t)=1 to write this, so how to show it?

Comment: @Koncopd Not sure of a rigourous way to show that, sorry. I think it's an assumption that $N_b,N_d$ are independent, and conditionally independent given an event defined on non-overlapping time periods, such as we have here.